# Kafka "Topic is empty" showing in UI after the producer code compilation successfully

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to write and run my own producer code so I have written the code in IntelliJ and compiled successfully with process finished with exit code 0.

But there has no message is showing in the UI, it is showing that the topic is empty, meanwhile if I am trying to produce some message using terminal in docker then the topic is behaving properly.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // kafka bootstrap server
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        // producer acks
        properties.setProperty("acks", "1");
        properties.setProperty("retries", "3");
        properties.setProperty("linger.ms", "1");

        Producer<String, String> producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);


        for (int key=0; key < 10; key++){
            ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord =
        new ProducerRecord<String, String>("second_topic", Integer.toString(key), "message that has key: " + Integer.toString(key));
            producer.send(producerRecord);
        }
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.dataoverflow.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-dataoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I have tried by adding Asynchronous Call Back Function in my code which is failing to push the message into Broker. What should I do?

```
package com.dataoverflow.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // kafka bootstrap server
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("broker.list", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        // producer acks
        properties.setProperty("acks", "all");
        properties.setProperty("timeout.ms", "20000");
      
        properties.setProperty("retries", "3");
        properties.setProperty("linger.ms", "10");
        //Specify buffer size in config
        properties.put("batch.size", 16384); 
        properties.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);

        Producer<String, String> producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);


        for (int key=0; key < 10; key++){
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record =
        new ProducerRecord<String, String>("second_topic", Integer.toString(key), "message that has key: " + Integer.toString(key));
            producer.send(record, new MyProducerCallback());
            System.out.println("AsynchronousProducer call completed");
        }
        producer.close();
    }
}

class MyProducerCallback implements Callback{

    
    public  void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            System.out.println("AsynchronousProducer failed with an exception");
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        else
            System.out.println("AsynchronousProducer call Success:");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
AsynchronousProducer failed with an exception
AsynchronousProducer call completed
AsynchronousProducer failed with an exception
AsynchronousProducer call completed
AsynchronousProducer failed with an exception
AsynchronousProducer call completed
AsynchronousProducer failed with an exception
AsynchronousProducer call completed
AsynchronousProducer failed with an exception
AsynchronousProducer call completed
```

Comment: First of all, I would add a Callback using onCompletion method in order to make sure that messages are pushed correctly into Kafka.

Comment: Second, can you please specify how are you running the jar file?

Comment: @dbustosp please check the update.

Comment: I am using Docker

Comment: Please when error is different to null use: e.printStackTrace(); and let me know what it says.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, anyway thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully fixed it. [Here](https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui/issues/119) is the thread.